# Shortcut for opening Windows 7 taskbar jumplist

Tags: windows-7, shortcut, taskbar, jump-list

I am looking for a shortcut for opening the Windows 7 taskbar jumplists.

This is an existing approach: `Win + Left Alt + 1, 2, 3 ...` Unfortunately you cannot use the numpad for the numbers, so I found this quite uncomfortable.

Alternatively, you can press `Win + T` to select the first item of the taskbar, after that you can move through the items by pressing `Left` or `Right`.

This is great, because you can press `Return`, `Shift + Return` or `Ctrl + Shift + Return` to achieve different tasks on the select taskbar item. However, I couldn't find a way to open the jumplist. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `Win + T` and after the selection of appropriate item, press the `Context Menu` Key

Comment: Windows + Alt + number is what he was looking for. In case someone else stumbles on this.

Comment: Well 0 works for #10 on the bar, but above that yes.

Comment: How to do this, if your notebook doesn't have a context menu key? (Shift+F10 didn't worked)